# How to display modal on button click

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, bootstrap-modal

I need to open a modal using button's `onclick`, but it is not succeeding. Are there any errors in my code?

**Add to Bag button**

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="addtobag" onclick="addTobag();">Add to Bag</button><br>
```

**Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addtobagmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                //mycode
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                //mycode
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                //mycode
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Function**

```
function addTobag() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
            if (request.responseText == "OK") {
                $('#addtobagmodal').modal('show');
            } else {
                alert('error');
            }
        }
    };
    request.open("GET", "myBag", true);
    request.send();
}
```

Comment: request.responseText = "OK"  I assume you intend **==**

Comment: does it work if `$('#addtobagmodal').modal('show');` is put without `XMLHttpRequest` ?

Comment: @gaetanoM thanx sir, my mistake. I edited it

Comment: @benjaminc still I get just error alert.

Comment: @PoornaSenaniGamage check ajax response, is it 200 ?

Comment: Your code works perfect. Unless there are issues in _myBag_ servlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `"myBag"` and its content.

Here is mode details :

There are two condition you are checking

First

```
if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200)
```

and second

```
if (request.responseText == "OK")
```

It means Model will only display when both condition are correct.

Create a text file `myBag.txt` apply OK  (only OK in that file)

Now use below code :

```js
function addTobag() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
            if (request.responseText == "OK") {
                $('#addtobagmodal').modal('show');
            } else {
                alert('error');
            }
        }
        else{
            alert('myBag file not found,  request.readyState = ' + request.readyState);
        }

    };
    request.open("GET", "myBag.txt", true);
    request.send();
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="addtobagmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                //mycode
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                //mycode
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                //mycode
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-default" id="addtobag" onclick="addTobag();">Add to Bag</button><br>
```

Here make sure that "myBag.txt" is on the same path on the HTML file.

Note file will be:

[image]

Comment: thanx for your explanation

Answer (score 2):

try below code. just added `js` and `css` libs for testing. see what you have missed in your code. for test click on **test** button to open the same popup.

```js
  function addTobag() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
        if (request.responseText = "OK") {
          $('#addtobagmodal').modal('show');
        } else {
          alert('error');
        }
      }
    };
    request.open("GET", "myBag", true);
    request.send();
  }

  function test() {
    $('#addtobagmodal').modal('show');
  }
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="btn btn-default" id="addtobag" onclick="addTobag();">Add to Bag</button><br>
    <button class="btn btn-default" id="addtobag" onclick="test();">Test modal only</button><br>

  <div class="modal fade" id="addtobagmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          //mycode
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          //mycode
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          //mycode
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try writing button code like

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="addTobag();>Add to Bag </button>
```

and using modal like

```
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                //mycode
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                //mycode
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                //mycode
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```